# Map within List - How to Iterate using Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

How to Iterate

```
List<Map<String, String>>
```

using streams..i have tried without streams and i was able to iterate.

```
for (Map<String, String> temp1 : maps){
                    for(Map.Entry<String, String> temp2: temp1.entrySet())
```

Is there a way to iterate using Streams..

Comment: What do you want the output to be? You usually use Streams to avoid explicit iteration.

Comment: Is there any way to use stream to iterate without using 2 for loops..

Comment: I think `flatMap` gets used for this, but then you just have one stream, so if you want to keep things as a list of some kind of collection, I don't think you can do that, unless you have some way of re-marshaling the data.

Comment: `maps.stream().flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())` will return a `stream` of all `Map.Entry<String, String>`

Comment: I personally find `Map.forEach()` cleaner than iterating over `Entry<String, String>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use stream you can iterate over values, keySet, entrySet: depending what you want to achieve. You need to specify what exactly You need.

Some code example below:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> lm = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

HashMap<String, String> m1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> m2 = new HashMap<String, String>();

m1.put("k1", "v1-m1");
m1.put("k2", "v2-m1");
m1.put("k3", "v3-m1");

m2.put("k1", "v1-m2");
m2.put("k3", "v1-m2");
m2.put("k3", "v1-m2");

lm.add(m1);
lm.add(m2);


lm.stream().forEach(e-> e.values().stream().forEach(ex-> System.out.println(ex)));
```

/Give the output:

```
v1-m1 
v2-m1 
v3-m1 
v1-m2 
v1-m2
```

Comment: While this uses streams, it is unnecessary overhead in this example. `stream().forEach()` can be replaced with just `Collection.forEach()`, avoiding the creation of a stream. Creating a stream is only necessary if the goal is to use more advanced features than `forEach`.

Comment: good point, I didnt think about that writing the code, 
But i used forEach, because forEach with sysout is the simplest way to create some example

Comment: But `lm.forEach(e-> e.values().forEach(ex-> System.out.println(ex)));` is even simpler…

Comment: I would avoid using such complex lambdas (which do multiple different things). You could do `lm.stream().map(Entry::values).flatMap(Collection::stream).forEach(System.out::println)` and wrap it nicely, 1 operation per line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Stream.flatMap(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) to iterate each map entry from the list of maps.

```
List<Map<String, String>> maps = ...
maps.stream()
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
    .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry));
```

From the docs:

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element.

Answer (score 1):

```
    List<Map<String,String>> maps = new LinkedList<Map<String,String>>();
            Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map1.put("key1", "value1");
            maps.add(map1);
            maps.stream().forEach(map -> 
map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println("key:"+k+" value:"+v)));
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to iterate, you don't need streams at all. Streams are useful to perform transformations on the elements, filter them or perform some reduction over them.

To only iterate, use `forEach`, both on the list and in its map elements:

```
maps.forEach(map -> map.forEach((key, value) -> /* use key and value here */));
```